# smarty fetch include on the fetched tpl page fails

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

My ajax php located in maindirexample/actions is calling a tpl file one folder up in maindirexample/templates

```
fetch('../templates/popupMyItems.tpl');
```

However this throws an error

```
<br /> <b>Fatal error</b>: Uncaught exception 'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'list-myItems.tpl' in '../templates/popupMyItems.tpl'
```

popupMyitems.tpl seems to be called ok, however list-myItems.tpl fails (this is included in popupMyitems.tpl) ..

```
{foreach
            from=$uniquecategories item=category name=cat} 
            {if $smarty.foreach.cat.first} {include file="list-myItems.tpl"
            category="{$category|replace:' ':''}" active="true"} 
            {else} {include
            file="list-myItems.tpl" category="{$category|replace:' ':''}"
            active="false"} {/if}

{/foreach}
```

Using

```
{include file="../templates/list-myItems.tpl"}
```

also fails :

```
'SmartyException' with message 'Unable to load template file 'list-myItems.tpl' in '../templates/popupMyItems.tpl'' in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ex\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ex\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_template.php(286): Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase-&gt;fetch(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, false, false, true) #1 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ex\main\actions\templates_c\07c3452c9173e47b89ab427877861e26b839928c.file.popupMyItems.tpl.php(52): Smarty_Internal_Template-&gt;getSubTemplate('list-myItems.tp...', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, Array, 0) #2 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ex\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(180): content_5236279826e113_69075833(Object(Smarty_Internal_Template)) #3 C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ex\main\actions in <b>C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\ex\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php</b> on line
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include it from ../templates/ as well. Smarty does not search the "current folder" for inclusions, but rather the include_dir specified in settings. So you should do something like this:

```
{include file="../templates/list-myItems.tpl" category="{$category|replace:' ':''}" active="true"}
```

Comment: thanks but it doesn't seem to work , I have tried it and updated the question

Comment: @Athanatos is the file `list-myItems.tpl` inside the same folder as `popupMyItems.tpl`?

Comment: @Athanatos what is your template_dir variable set to?

Comment: it's the default templatedir , I  am not setting it explicitly to anything .. I got it to at least not to throw an error by calling it like so : $smarty->fetch('../templates/popupMyItems.tpl',$h); note: $h is  a var set to 0 , no idea why it doesn't crash this way ...however it throws an undefined error for a variable that I have defined and I can print in PHP and I am assigning it through smarty.. very strange.

Comment: ok I realized what happens when I pass h through, uniquecategories is not passed through therefore the conditions of the for loop (Above) are never met, so it doesn't actually check for the include that's why it seems to work.. so the problem remains

Comment: it was resolved the second include in the else of the foreach  also needed ../templates, thanks